# howto disable compile of modules when tests are skipepd

Tags: maven-2, build

In our "big build" (40+ modules), we have several modules that contain only tests.

When I give -DskiptTests to mvn, the tests are not executed.

But they are compiled, which costs up to a minute of build time.

How can I selectively turn off such modules when the option skipTests is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to organize your root pom such that the test modules are activated via a profile, and instead of using `-Dmaven.test.skip` to turn use `-P!testProfile` to deactivate them and hence skipping them.

Another thought is that you could just do:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I haven't actually tried that... it should in theory work. I seem to remember that the `<skip>` configuration is on all plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the Gareth David point:

- When you run `mvn ... -DskipTests`, only the **execution** of tests is skipped. This is the same behavior if you run `mvn ... -Dtest=notest`
- When you run `mvn ... -Dmaven.skip.test=true`, then **both** test execution and compilation are skipped.

So the second command is enough, without any modification of your `pom.xml` file.

([source](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html))

Comment: @Bastl What is the version of Maven you are using?